# SQL calculate discount when SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to select my Database for a table and want to calculate the Discount with the pricebefore and price (thats the price now) when SELECT.

This is my query

```
$sql = "SELECT *, SUM((pricebefore - price ) / price * 100) AS discount FROM products  WHERE price IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT $no_of_records_per_page OFFSET $offset";
```

So i want to get ALL data, and SUM the pricebefore - price than  / price and * 100 so that i get the percentual discount and want to safe it AS discount.

But i get all time this error:

```
Query failed: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying - character varying
LINE 1: SELECT *, SUM((pricebefore - price ) / price * 100) AS disco...
                                   ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

But why... i dont find the problem, tried much things like without SUM or something but nothing works

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The use of `SUM()` with `SELECT *` implies that you don't really know how SQL queries work.  It is better to see the data and results, rather than a non-sensical query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `price_before` is in the same row, you don't need `sum()`.

```
SELECT p.*, (p.pricebefore - p.price ) / p.price * 100 AS discount
FROM products
WHERE price IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT $no_of_records_per_page OFFSET $offset;
```

It would appear that `pricebefore` and `price` are strings and not numbers.  MySQL would normally convert them, but you can do an explicit conversion:

```
SELECT p.*, ( cast(p.pricebefore as numeric(20, 4)) - cast(p.price as numeric(20, 4)) / cast(p.price as numeric(20, 40)) * 100 AS discount
FROM products
WHERE price IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID DESC
LIMIT $no_of_records_per_page OFFSET $offset;
```

Comment: I tried your code, but than i get `Query failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: &quot;6,99&quot;`